# Wix: remove local app data for all users

Tags: wix, wix3.6

In my wix installer I need to remove all app data created by an application for all users during uninstall. I can easily delete it for the current user but not for all users. Is there a way to do it other than creating a custom action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no *easy* way to do it for other users.

The only thing you can do is to go into each user's profile and try to remove the files there. This would work for local users. But it won't work as you expect for roaming profile users.

Thus applications usually leave their stuff in user profiles when they're uninstalled.

Comment: You could always store your files in e.g. "C:\ProgramData\YourApp\username". That way, you *can* remove them easily on uninstallation.